Error backing up the Certificate using the Master Key in SQL Server
I am trying to backup my Certificate and Master Key in my local machine to migrate to the server.
The reason is, when I migrate the data to the server without this certificate and key, the migrated data is null when trying to decrypt the original value.
First, i already backed up my Key and it executed properly.
USE myDB;
GO

BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'myKeyBackUpPath'
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'myPassword';
GO

Then when I tried backing up my certificate
USE myDB;
GO

BACKUP CERTIFICATE MyCertificate
    TO FILE = 'myCertificateBackupPath'
    WITH PRIVATE KEY (
        FILE = 'myKeyBackUpPath',
        ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'myPassword'
    );
GO

It goes with an error

Cannot write into file 'myKeyBackUpPath'. Verify that you have write permissions, that the file path is valid, and that the file does not already exist.

Now, I already check the permission of the folders, and the exact file and modified the security that I have a full control, write, modify, etc.
But still the error occurs.
Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

What in the...
Ok ok. I am newly wake up, so here is the solution. My bad.
You don't need to execute the first Statement.
USE myDB;
GO

BACKUP MASTER KEY TO FILE = 'myKeyBackUpPath'
    ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'myPassword';
GO

And you must execute the second statement instead alone to backup both certificate and symmetric key.
My bad. Thanks
